# Embedded linux setup PCIe IPC transfer data line

Tags: c, embedded-linux, pci-bus

I am doing Embedded linux with QC RB5 Development Kit it have PCIe on the kit, and i wish to use it as IPC with another board ambarella cv5 development kit with PCIe too, which to send high speed data to and flow back, by wire both PCIE connected to each other, I try to use memory map (mmap) for PCIe device for both and write data to it and read from another side, it not showing any result. Is it doable? should i use DMA ? and in the lspci it show bridge for PCIE, is that allow to use? and do I need to change CV5 board to endpoint?

I have try with https://github.com/billfarrow/pcimem and read and write to the address but there is no data been send.

Comment: Have you chance to read PCIe specifications?